# node js function could not stop executing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wrote this node js function for google cloud function to index firebase database node entry to Algolia.

```
exports.indexlisting_algolia = 
 functions.database.ref('/Listings/{listingId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const index = algolia.initIndex('Listings');
    const before = change.before;  // snapshot before the update
    const after = change.after;    // snapshot after the update
    const before_data = before.val();
    const after_data = after.val();
    after_data.objectID = context.params.listingId;
    console.log(Date.now());
            console.log(context)

return index.saveObject(after_data)

 .then(
  () => change.after.ref.child('last_index_timestamp').set(

     Date.parse(context.timestamp)));


})
```

the function works but it would not stop executing, it just keep repeating itself over and over again. What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By doing `change.after.ref.child('last_index_timestamp').set()` you are writing to the reference you are listening to in your Cloud Function. So the Cloud Function is auto-triggering itself.

You should check at the beginning of the function if it needs to be executed or not.

Most probably you would check if `last_index_timestamp` exists or has a specific value, by using `change.before.val()` and/or `change.after.val()`.

If you want to stop the execution of the Function just return `null`.

See the following official sample for an example of this "technique" (lines 30 to 32) https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/952fe5d08c0a416f78def93fa337ca2bd73aedcf/message-translation/functions/index.js

---

A last (important) remark: you shall return the promise returned by the `set()` method as well as catch the potential errors, as follows:

```
 return index.saveObject(after_data)
 .then(
  () => return change.after.ref.child('last_index_timestamp').set(Date.parse(context.timestamp))
 )
 .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error:', err);
    return false;
  });
```

I would suggest that you watch the following official Video Series "Learning Cloud Functions for Firebase" (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/), and in particular the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises", which explain how and why we should chain and return promises in event triggered Cloud Functions.

Comment: the addition of return before change.after is generating error